# Python. What str.attribute could be used in key argument of method sort? set.sort(key)

Tags: python, sorting, set

I'm a newbie just reading Lutz, so the example is partly from that book:

```
l = ['aBe', 'ABD', 'abc'] #the following listing works ok
l.sort(key=str.lower)
l
>>>['abc', 'ABD', 'aBe']
```

And the quesition is what str.attribute could be used in that case?

```
l.sort(key=str.replace('Be', 'aa')) #why does not this works for example?
```

Thanks a lot for the answers, please don't judge harshly;)

Comment: `A < a` `A.lower() == a`, how do you think that would affect the sort order?  As for `str.replace('Be', 'aa')`, how could that possibly work? calling `str.replace('Be', 'aa')` alone would not work. The key should be callable where each element in the list is passed to the callable.

Comment: Because your missing a parenthesis?

Comment: What's the expected behavior in the case of `l.sort(key=str.replace('Be', 'aa'))`? You need to pass a function there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I  commented, the key must be a callable, to do what you are trying to do you could use a *lambda* with chained `str.replace` calls like `x.replace("B","a").replace("e","a")` but a better solution would be to use *str.translate*:

```
tbl = {ord("B"):"a", ord("e"):"a"}

l.sort(key=lambda x: x.translate(tbl))
```

Or use [operator.methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) as  *Bakuriu* commented:

```
from operator import methodcaller

key=methodcaller('translate', tbl)
```

If you just want to match the full substring then it is a simple `l.sort(key=lambda x: x.replace("Be","aa"))` or `l.sort(key=methodcaller("replace","Be","aa"))`.

Comment: Or you can use [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller): `key=methodcaller('translate', tbl)`.

Comment: str.replace('Be', 'aa')
but isn't it callable? It will return 'aaa', 'ABD' and 'abc' for the elements in the list the same as 
str.lower
returns them in a lower case

Comment: @Ilya, `TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`, it causes an error so definitely not callable.

Comment: l.sort(key=str.lower), in this case items of the set are not passed as the arguments to the function lower(), lower is called as an attribute of str objects from the set. Or attribute is a link to the function with one argument?

Comment: `str.replace(self, old, new, count)` so calling `key=str.replace('Be', 'aa')` you are missing new so you get the error as it is called straight away. `str.lower(self)` so `key=str.lower` gets each string passed in as self.

Comment: df=lambda x: return str.replace(x, 'Be', 'aa'); l.sort(key=df) #it works but I'm not sure it is the best way)

Comment: @Ilya, that is bascially the same as  `lambda x: x.replace( 'Be', 'aa')`, it is the like doing `instance.method()` vs `SomeClass.method(instance)`